# Setting parameter in Gradle with arguments

Tags: gradle

Is it possible to type some arguments for a gradle script and this arguments are read in the script to complete some parameters?

Example:

```
productFlavors {
 full {
     resValue "string", "app_flavor", "full"
     resValue "string", "chat_contact",$arg1
 }
 free {
     minSdkVersion 16
     targetSdkVersion 22
     versionCode 22
     resValue "string", "app_flavor", "free"
     resValue "string", "chat_contact",$arg2
 }
```

}

Where $arg1 and $arg2 were typed in the command line (e.g. gradle -Parg1=sergio -Parg2=lauriano

Tks

Comment: There is simply no need to use the `$` notation. Project properties (like the ones provided via `-Pkey=value`) are directly added to the [`Project`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) scope. You only need the notation in GStrings, like `"My name is $name"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options to achieve what you want:

- Under the hood of Gradle there is a Groovy language which supports string interpolation e.g. you can wrap your parameter into string like this

  `resValue "string", "chat_contact", "$arg1"`
- Another options is to use parameter as a reference to gradle project property e.g.

  `resValue "string", "chat_contact", arg1`

  however in this case if you miss variable in command line you will receive an error to avoid this you can define default values for parameters in **gradle.properties**.

Comment: Thanks. This answer was very helpful. I can do what I wanted in my script.